# How to render a ForeignKey field as CharField in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

My Model

```
class Collaborator(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

My Form:

```
class CollaboratorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Collaborator
        fields = ('user',)
```

The template render the user input text as an `autocomplete` field loaded from `User` model.

The page shows the user input text field correctly, however when I go to edit a Collaborator the user input text field **shows the user Id** and **I want to show the username** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to figure out first what the exact behavior you want is.

Let's say I'm user with id=1, username="Joel". When you produce your CollaboratorForm and it shows "Joel" (my username) on the form and you edit it to read "Jane", are you:

- trying to edit my name to "Jane", so that id=1 now has a username=Jane ?
- or trying to change the associated user to the user matching that username?

Once you know that, you can proceed.

I'd change the `user = forms.CharField(..)` to `username = forms.CharField(..)`; that's what your really showing, after all.

In your view, when you create your form, pass it the initial values of `{'username':username-of-user-that-is-currently-related}`.

In your view, when you process the form, before you save it, use the `cleaned_data['username']` to either (a) update the username of that user (if the first case above) or (b) get the ID of the new user and save that to the `.user` field (if the second case above).

Of course, if what you want is really at a higher-level "let people pick the user based on the username", you might be able to solve this differently and more easily--by not using a CharField at all, and using a ChoiceField instead, so you could show a drop down menu of users with the key=ID and value=name. Depending on how many users you have, though, that might not scale well.

Comment: I added "The template render the user input text as an `autocomplete` field loaded from `User` model." to my original question. In my case I'm  trying to change the associated user to the user matching that username. So as you suggested I changed `user` to `username`; override the `__init__` and add `self.fields['username'].initial = self.instance.user`; and had set the `user` on clean_username.